# How to find columns get affected in sql server update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a log table columns like below

```
   [Id]      
  ,[Attribute]
  ,[Action]
  ,[OldValue]
  ,[NEwValue]
  ,[UserId]
  ,[ModifiedDate]
```

where id is row id getting affected . attribute is the column being affected . Action is "insert " or "update' depending on na type of operation being performed . 
In case of update old value and new value of the column being updated should be inserted  to newValue nad old Value columns in log table .

Wat is the best possible way to achieve this. Should I go for triggers or stored procedure .?

Comment: Triggers are new to me . can u post the update trigger for this . So that i can refer to

Comment: Go for Stored procedure and use output clause .

Answer (score 2):

Did you check about "Change Data Capture" introduced in SQL Server 2008? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Try the following sample code

```
-- Temp table to track changes
DECLARE  @tmpTable TABLE
(
     [Id]  INT   IDENTITY(1,1)     
    ,[Attribute]   VARCHAR(10)
    ,[Action]   VARCHAR(50)
    ,[OldValue]   VARCHAR(50)
    ,[NEwValue]   VARCHAR(50)
    ,[UserId]   INT 
    ,[ModifiedDate]  DATETIME

)

-- Actual/Transaction table
DECLARE @tblMyTable TABLE
(
        ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Name VARCHAR(50)
)

-- Sample insert query
INSERT      INTO    @tblMyTable
OUTPUT      'Name'
            ,'Inserted'
            ,NULL -- Old value is null
            ,inserted.Name
            ,1 -- user ID
            ,GETDATE()

INTO        @tmpTable 
VALUES      ('New Name');


-- Sample update query
UPDATE      @tblMyTable
SET         Name = 'Updated Name'
OUTPUT      
            'Name'
            ,'Updated'
            ,deleted.Name -- Old value is null
            ,inserted.Name
            ,1 -- user ID
            ,GETDATE()

INTO        @tmpTable


select * from @tblMyTable
select * from @tmpTable
```

Answer (score 2):

i found the solution . posting here fa others use

```
 CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tb_sample_UpdationTrigger] on [dbo].[tb_sample]  for UPDATE
    as
     if UPDATE(R_Id) 
     insert into dbo.test_log(Attribute,Action,OldValue,NEwValue,UserId,ModifiedDate)
    (SELECT 'R_Id','update', d.R_Id, i.R_Id ,1,GETDATE()
    FROM inserted i
    INNER JOIN deleted d ON d.id=i.id
    INNER JOIN tb_sample ON tb_sample.id=i.id)
```